# Editing contentboxes HTML manually

Tags: html, content, html-editor

Basically, I want to edit the html that represent the content-boxes on my website in SharePoint Designer. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If it was me I would create a folder in site assets using Designer, then create file.html inside of that, and start editing.  Then link the CEWP (Content Editor Web Part) to the location of that file.